# CMake Generator is not passed to Conan when Cross Compiling

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to setup an embedded CMake Project using Conan with GCC arm none eabi and Ninja Generator.

I already did manage to setup Windows (Ninja) and Linux (WSL2) builds.
Now I'm moving on to building an embedded target.

from a cmake preset USE_SPDLOG is set to "1.8.5",

Now my Conan workflow is as recommended in https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan

```
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)

 if(USE_SPDLOG)
    set(SPDLOG_PACKAGE "spdlog/${USE_SPDLOG}")
    set(SPDLOG_ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS "spdlog:header_only=True")
  endif()

 conan_cmake_configure(
    REQUIRES
    ${SPDLOG_PACKAGE}
    OPTIONS
    ${SPDLOG_ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS}
    GENERATORS cmake_find_package)

  conan_cmake_autodetect(settings)

 conan_cmake_install(
    PATH_OR_REFERENCE
    .
    BUILD
    missing
    REMOTE
    conan-center
    SETTINGS
    ${OS_SETTING}
    ${OS_VERSION_SETTING}
    ${ARCH_SETTING}
    ${settings})

 list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

  if(USE_SPDLOG)
    conan_find_package(spdlog)
  endif()
```

Now Cmake detects my Crosscompiler  (GCC 10.2, arm none eabi) properly

```
 [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/xxxx/toolchains/arm-none-eabi-gcc-10.2.1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe - skipped
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/xxxx/toolchains/arm-none-eabi-gcc-10.2.1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe - skipped
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
1> [CMake] -- Found assembler: C:/xxxx/toolchains/arm-none-eabi-gcc-10.2.1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe
```

So within my project gcc + ninja seam to work.

However conan starts with

```
[CMake] -- Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan
1> [CMake] -- Conan: checking conan executable
1> [CMake] -- Conan: Found program C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/conan.exe
1> [CMake] -- Conan: Version found Conan version 1.42.1
1> [CMake] -- Conan executing: C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/conan.exe install . --remote conan-center --build missing --settings build_type=Debug --settings compiler=gcc --settings compiler.version=10 --settings compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
1> [CMake] Configuration:
1> [CMake] [settings]
1> [CMake] arch=x86_64
1> [CMake] arch_build=x86_64
1> [CMake] build_type=Debug
1> [CMake] compiler=gcc
1> [CMake] compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
1> [CMake] compiler.version=10
1> [CMake] os=Windows
1> [CMake] os_build=Windows
1> [CMake] [options]
1> [CMake] [build_requires]
1> [CMake] [env]
1> [CMake]
```

=>I believe conan does not actually cross compile

From the conan docs
https://docs.conan.io/en/1.6/systems_cross_building/cross_building.html

I tried adding

```
os_build=none
arch_build=arm
os=Windows
arch=x86_64
compiler=Visual Studio
```

to the options

but this results in

```
ERROR: Invalid setting 'none
1> [CMake]     arch_build=arm
1> [CMake]     os=Windows
1> [CMake]     arch=x86_64
1> [CMake]     compiler=Visual Studio' is not a valid 'settings.os_build' value.
```

So how do I get embedded cross compilation to work? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You seem to have things mixed up according to the documentation: `arch_build` is for the build system, i.e. the system and `arch` is for the host system (which for some reason here seems to be similar to the target system; not familiar with conan, so I cannot tell the difference without some research). Therefore the since you're compiling for Linux arm it should probably be `arch_build=x86_64` `os_build=Windows` `os=Linux` and `arch=arm` In the linked site the section Windows to Raspberry and below should list examples; you may want/need to specify an arm version(ARM architecture reference)...

Answer (score 0):

If I get the documentation right you have to define the host-os as windows, if you want to crosscompile on this platform.

From the documentation:

```
Build platform: The platform on which the compilation tools are executed
```

Comment: Hey, thx, I rearranged the settings to ``set(settings 
     #host
    "os_build=Windows"
    "arch_build=x86_64"
    #Target
    "os=none"
    "arch_target=arm"
    "compiler=gcc")`` now I'm getting. "ERROR: Invalid setting 'arm' is not a valid 'settings.arch_target' value.
Possible values are ['x86', 'x86_64', 'ppc32be', 'ppc32', 'ppc64le', 'ppc64', 'armv5el', 'armv5hf', 'armv6', 'armv7', 'armv7hf', 'armv7s', 'armv7k', 'armv8', 'armv8_32', 'armv8.3', 'sparc', 'sparcv9', 'mips', 'mips64', 'avr', 's390', 's390x', 'asm.js', 'wasm', 'sh4le', 'e2k-v2', 'e2k-v3', 'e2k-v4', 'e2k-v5']

Comment: I'm guessing arm-none is not supported by conan?